# Multi-character batch choice menu

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Quick question:
I've seen single-character choice menus in batch files everywhere but how do you make multiple character choice menus?

Here's an example (doesn't work):

```
@echo off
echo Example Menu
GOTO AGAIN

:AGAIN
   CD /D "%~dp0"
   echo Restore, Apps, Restart

   set /p answer=
   if /i "%answer:~,1%" EQU "1" GOTO RESTORE
   if /i "%answer:~,1%" EQU "2" GOTO APPS
   if /i "%answer:~,1%" EQU "0" shutdown -t 0 -r -f

   if "answer"=="restore" GOTO RESTORE
   if "answer"=="apps" GOTO APPS
   if "answer"=="restart" shutdown -t 0 -r -f

:RESTORE
    start systempropertiesprotection -k
    GOTO AGAIN

:APPS
    start appwiz.cpl -k
    GOTO AGAIN
```

Comment: A single-character menu based on `choice` command have the advantage that avoids user errors "automatically" and are very simple (the option input and selection takes _two commands_: `choice` and `goto option-%errorlevel%`). In a multiple character menu, you have to test that users input is correct (because they may enter _any string_), so they are more complex...

Comment: I will only use it myself for shortcuts for different tools I need for work so user error is null since I will know what I have to enter for every one of them. But there are getting close to 50 and so I used up most of the keys on the keyboard, had to do something about it.

Comment: You may subdivide many options in several nested sub-menus. If a menu have more than 15-20 options, it is difficult to read. On the other hand, if you already know the name of the 50 options, then the presentation of the menu is useless...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the variable `"%answer%"`, not the string `"answer"`.

```
@echo off
echo Example Menu

:AGAIN
   CD /D "%~dp0"
   echo Restore, Apps, Restart

   set /p answer=

   if /i "%answer%" == "restore" GOTO RESTORE
   if /i "%answer%" == "apps" GOTO APPS
   if /i "%answer%" == "restart" GOTO RESTART

   echo That was not a valid option.
   GOTO AGAIN

:RESTORE
    echo You want to restore?
    GOTO AGAIN

:APPS
    echo You want apps?
    GOTO AGAIN

:RESTART
    echo You want to restart?
    GOTO AGAIN
```

Comment: Wow. I wasn't paying attention when I put " instead of %. Good point, thanks!